# Stochastic Differential of an Integral where the Integrand is a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

This is an exercise in Bjork's book, (not an assignment or homework, I am trying to solve all the exercises to improve my fundamentals as a beginner)

$$ Z_t = \int_0^t g_s \, dW_s $$

The question asks to find the stochastic differential where g is an adapted stochastic process.

I'm not sure if this problem requires some form of substitution but I am getting thrown off by the fact that g(s) is a stochastic adapted process. (I assume that means it is a stochastic process with some form of diffusion from W.)

Naively applying Ito's lemma gives us a time derivative (Which I have no idea what to do with), a derivative with respect to W, which I assume cancels out the integral and gives us the integrand, and then a second derivative with respect to the stochastic process (assumed to be deterministic before plugging in the stochastic variable)

$$ dZ_t = \frac{dZ}{dt}.dt + \frac{dZ}{dx}.dx + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2Z}{dx^2}.dx^2 $$

Where $$ dX_t = 1.dW_t$$

I can intuitively see what happens to the second term but the rest of the two terms are something I struggle to make sense of. I imagine this is a pretty basic problem since I cannot find any thread with exactly this (where g is non-deterministic) so I must be missing something basic.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Somewhat confused by your question. It's simply $dZ_t = g_t \,dW_t$. It's (typically) just a shorthand for an integral equation. But that can't be what the exercise is asking for (?).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I believed that it can't be that straightforward. The exercise is in a section where you're asked to compute dZ_t for the subquestions. All the others have a straightforward Z(x,t) formulation with no integrals in them accept this one and take a bit of algebra.

I think I see what you mean though.

Comment: In that case it might just be what they ask for, to trip you up.

Comment: In that case I feel rather silly for the time I spent on this, but thanks for helping me clear that up! Should I close this question as un-informative?

Comment: I tried writing a somewhat informative answer, so maybe it can stay.

Comment: @fibonachoceres . You don't need Ito's formula here. $Z_t$ does not depend on $x$ and on $t$ only in a non differentiable way. Stefan's answer is on point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply $dZ_t = g_t\,dW_t$. The differential notion is just a shorthand for an integral equation. If, say, $Z_t = f(W_t)$, then of course you'd use Ito's formula, but this isn't the case here.

More generally

$$X_t = X_s + \int_s^t b(t,X_t)\,dt + \int_s^t \sigma(t,X_t)\,dW_t$$

can be written as

$$dX_t = b(t,X_t)\,dt + \sigma(t,X_t)\,dW_t,$$

perhaps with extra information about what the initial value is.

It's used pretty much regardless of how complicated $g$ is, whether $g$ is deterministic, of the form $g_t = h(t,W_t)$, $g_t = h(t, Z_t)$ or even $g_t = h(\omega, t, Z_t)$, where $\omega\in \Omega$ (the sample space), in mean-field equations, etc. etc.